# Is there a text on estimation theory online?

Tags: st.statistics, estimation-theory, books

Where can I find graduate level, thorough, parameter estimation/ estimation theory material on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was referred to this text:
Hogg/Craig, Introduction to mathematical statistics. Prentice-Hall
After browsing through a bit I found it to be not so suitable and often garbled.

**UPDATE**
And here is one which fit my needs better:
Kay S.M. Fundamentals of statistical signal processing: estimation theory